# Gatsby sitemap generator isn't filterting the pages

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm trying to generate sitemaps via `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` and it works with all the default options and generate the sitemaps however if I try to modify the sitemap generation in anyway it doesn't seems to have any affect whatsoever e.g. I want to remove the changefreq and priority, it doesn't work and when I try to filter the pages it doesn't work either.

This is how my config looks like:

```
{
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
            options: {
                output: `/testsitemap.xml`,
            },
            query: `{
                        site {
                            siteMetadata {
                                siteUrl
                            }
                        }
                        allJsonJson {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    noindex
                                    hrefs {
                                        href
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }`,
            serialize: ({ site, allJsonJson }) => {
                return allJsonJson.edges
                    .filter(({node}) => (
                        node.noindex !== true
                    ))
                    .map(({node}) => {
                        node.hrefs.map(({href}) => {
                            return {
                               url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${href}`
                            };
                        })
                     })
            },
        }
```

This is driving me nuts as I'm trying to make it work for quite sometime now and can't proceed at all. Any ideas?

GraphQL Editor:

```
"allJsonJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "noindex": null,
            "hrefs": [
              {
                "href": "/about/"
              },
              {
                "href": "/aa/test.../"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: Is the `node` returning an object with the `noindex` property?

Comment: In the GraphQL editor it is but I haven't tested it in the actual code.

Comment: I tried to put console log in there but it didn't work. Not sure how to test it.

Comment: Placing a `console.log()` in a Node file will prompt it in the IDE console, or wherever you use the running command.

Comment: Well, I realized why none of the changes were working. I didn't put it inside the ```options``` object. However now, the error says ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Putting console.log didn't work either. It doesn't output anything in the terminal at all.

Comment: Well, at that point your code is breaking so it can't display anything. Your `hrefs` is not a loopable element, maybe it's an object or maybe a string.

Comment: ```hrefs``` is an array and I tested the same code in the test script and it works. Let me modify the original post to include the result of GraphQL editor.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the plugin doesn't support anything other than `allSitePage` as mentioned in this [ticket](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25019).

Answer (score 1):

I nearly moved to Next.js trying to figure this out...

```js
 {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            allSitePage {
              nodes {
                path
                pageContext
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        resolveSiteUrl: () => 'https://yourwebsite.com/',
        resolvePages: ({ allSitePage: { nodes: allPages } }) => {
          return allPages.filter((page) => {
            // Don't want to add private routes to the sitemap
            if (page.path.includes('/dashboard')) {
              return false;
            }

            return true;
          });
        },
      },
    },
```